# Address and coordinates of European cities request

Tags: gps, geocoding, europe

I have a database of couple of millions of records which I would like to geocode. The data consists of addresses and council. All addresses are of a certain European city.

Questions:

- May I have accurate coordinates with a free/low cost geocoder? If yes, which one?
- Can I buy from a company (like TomTom) for a fee, street address, number, postcode, council and accurate coordinates of European cities? Estimates of the fee price?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achive you goal using free geocoders with a little bit of scripting on top. First you should probalby look into the OpenStreetMap Nominatim (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) Here however there are certain use policies that you  must apply to.

In the link i have give you, it is stated, that Mapbox have a similar service with no restrictions - i am not sure that that still is the case.

Instead of buying data you should look into the possibility of downloadning your own OSM data and set up a geocoding logic based on that - it requires a little work, but it is however completly free...

Comment: Morten, thank you for your answer. We do have the data available but this constists of 100 million of records or so and it will take ages to geocode for free (and quality will not be guaranteed). Thus, we are mostly interested in licensing already-geocoded addresses of European cities. Is there any such third-party able to license this data?